# XML Serializing a generic list with an additional property

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, serialization

I need to create an object model that serializes to this:

```
<RootItem>
    <PropertySet name="SomePropList">
        <Property name="SomeProp" value="SomeValue"/>
    </PropertySet>
</RootItem>
```

I cannot figure this out.  I have the following:

```
[XmlRoot("RootItem")]
public class RootItem
{
    public AuthResponse()
    { 
        PropertySet = new PropertySet();
    }

    public PropertySet PropertySet { get; set; }
}

    
public class PropertySet : List<Property>
{
    public PropertySet()
    {
    }

     [XmlAttribute]
     public string name { get; set; }
}


[XmlType("Property")]
public class Property
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, when it serialies it ignores the name attribute and I get this instead:

```
<RootItem>
    <PropertySet>
        <Property name="externalId" value="55555555"/>
    </PropertySet>
</RootItem>
```

What type of Object Model/tricks/attributes do I need to make this serialize WITH the name property in PropertySet?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that looks like this for PropertySet and Property:

```
public class PropertySet
{
    public PropertySet()
    {
        Properties = new List<Property>();
    }
    
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Property")]
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }    
}

[XmlType("Property")]
public class IgtProperty
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

The big takeaway being that you can inherit your class from generic collection, rather you have to have the list contained in your class with the other props you want serialized and then use XmlElement to control the naming of all the items so it doesn't do the <List><ListItem></List> approach